# Deploying an angular application in hyperledger-composer

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I have my `composer-rest-server` running on port 3000 and now I try to generate an angular application with `yo hyperledger-composer` following the [tutorial](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/tutorials/developer-guide.html).

**Steps creating the webapp:**

[image: screenshot]

After I do `npm start` and it seems that the webapp es correctly created because I am able to reach it from the localhost with `curl localhost:4200` but when I try to reach it from another host I get nothing.

Both hosts are connected because I can reach the composer server running on port 3000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change your Angular app's configuration info (for the install) - it is based on your currently configured IP address, that you want to access from 'remote':

1) Change your Angular skeleton app - eg. for application named `my-app` - its  the file `my-app/src/app/configuration.ts` (where my-app is the generated app dir). For the network interface/resolvable host you chose, change the property:

`public ApiIP: string = "localhost";`

to be your IP or resolvable host.

2) After building, you can change it as you wish - specifically where it says `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` to `ng serve --host {MY_IP}` in your `package.json`(leave the rest in!)- see example below:

```
    "start": "concurrently \"ng serve --host 10.0.0.1\" \"npm run my-app\"",
```

Comment: Same problem, I can still reach it from localhost but no from the other host

Comment: Solved, just writing `--host` in the package.json file it worked!

Comment: hi, I've updated the answer (above), and thanks for your comment.